# MariaDB unnecessary AUTO_INCREMENT with ON DUPLICATE clause

Tags: insert, mariadb, auto-increment

I have a table, I named 'srcCodDsc', that has 3 column:

- ID : INT PRIMARY KEY with AUTO_INCREMENT
- locId : VARCHAR
- locDsc : VARCHAR

I also defined an unique index on locId, to avoid duplication of a locId value.

Now the problem :

```
INSERT INTO srcCodDsc (locId,locDsc) VALUES ('012_002','value to set') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE locDsc=VALUES(locDsc);
```

The query update correctly the locDsc value of the row with locId = '012_002', but I discover that the AUTO_INCREMENT next value counter is incremented at every execution of the query, even if a new line is not inserted.

I check it with command:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='berna' AND TABLE_NAME='srcCodDsc';
```

How to turn the query into a conditional form that, after checking if the record with locId = '012_002' exists, in one case does insert, in the other one does update and if locDsc is already worth the new value does nothing?

NOTE: the same query in mySql works and not update auto_increment next value.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, various `INSERT`-like statements quickly grab the `AUTO_INCREMENT` values that it *might* need, then they proceed to do the query.  In your case, the id was not needed, so it was "burned".

I believe this works the same in both MySQL and MariaDB.  If you are finding a difference, please provide the version numbers of both, plus the value of the variable `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`.

Note also:  (before MySQL 8.0) If you stop and restart MySQL/MariaDB between burning the *last* id in the table, that id will be reused.  (This leads to a different type of surprise, hence the change in 8.0.)